# .NET Core SingleFile publish, get temp folder

Tags: .net-core, exe, temp

i published my exe as Single file.
And i included a file to my project:

```
    <ItemGroup>
       <None Update="python_base64.txt">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
       </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

When i check AppData temp folder, i saw this: [image]

In this folder i have my python_base64.txt file(when i run published exe file). How can i access to that folder in my code?

Edit:
i did this:

```
public static string GetTempFolder()
{
    string parentTemp = Path.GetTempPath() + ".net\\" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
    string[] paths = Directory.GetDirectories(parentTemp);
    List<string> orderedPaths = paths.OrderByDescending(s => Directory.GetCreationTime(s)).ToList();
    return orderedPaths[0];
}
```

Comment: Don't look in the temp directory, only look at the publish directory.